# Under what conditions is a flight attendant required on an aircraft?

Tags: faa-regulations, flight-attendant

Not all airplanes with passengers are required to have flight attendants.

What are the regulations that cover this and when are they required?

Answer (score 12):

14 CFR Part § 121.391.

It depends on the size/weight of the airplane and how many passengers it can hold

> Except as specified in § 121.393 and § 121.394, each certificate
>   holder must provide at least the following flight attendants on board
>   each passenger-carrying airplane when passengers are on board:
>
> 1. For airplanes having a maximum payload capacity of more than 7,500 pounds
>      and having a seating capacity of more than 9 but less than 51
>      passengers—**one flight attendant.**
> 2. For airplanes having a maximum
>      payload capacity of 7,500 pounds or less and having a seating capacity
>      of more than 19 but less than 51 passengers—**one flight attendant**.
> 3. For airplanes having a seating capacity of more than 50 but less than
>      101 passengers—**two flight attendants**.
> 4. For airplanes having a seating capacity of more than 100 passengers—**two flight 
>      attendants plus one additional flight attendant for each unit (or part of a unit)
>      of 50 passenger seats above a seating capacity of 100 passengers**.

http://www.gpo.gov/fdsys/pkg/CFR-2011-title14-vol3/pdf/CFR-2011-title14-vol3-sec121-391.pdf

Parts § 121.393,394 relax these requirements when a plane stops, but denotes how close by the flight attendants must be, and other things like exit door requirements.

Remember, Flight Attendants are there for your safety :) which is the motivation for these regulations.

[Edit]
14 CFR Part 91.533 covers flights operated under "Part 91" regulations:

§ 91.533 Flight attendant requirements.

> 1. No person may operate an airplane unless at least the following number of flight attendants are on board the airplane:
>
>    - For airplanes having more than 19 but less than 51 passengers on board, one flight attendant.
>    - For airplanes having more than 50 but less than 101 passengers on board, two flight attendants.
>    - For airplanes having more than 100 passengers on board, two flight attendants plus one additional flight attendant for each unit (or part
>        of a unit) of 50 passengers above 100.
> 2. No person may serve as a flight attendant on an airplane when required by paragraph (a) of this section unless that person has
>      demonstrated to the pilot in command familiarity with the necessary
>      functions to be performed in an emergency or a situation requiring
>      emergency evacuation and is capable of using the emergency equipment
>      installed on that airplane.

It looks like the "training" to act as a Part 91 Flight Attendant is just showing the pilot they are capable.

The big difference between Part 121 and Part 91, is *number of seats (potential capacity)* vs. *people actually on board*.  This is interesting in light of the recent 787 Boeing Business Jet deliveries (http://boeing.mediaroom.com/2014-02-05-Boeing-Business-Jets-Delivers-First-Two-BBJ-787-8s-of-2014).  So if it was just the owner and the pilot crew, there wouldn't need to be a flight attendant (assuming, of course, they're operating under Part 91), even though it is a huge plane.

Comment: What about non-121 flights?

Comment: § 91.533 covers this.  It seems like the Flight Attendant qualifications are little relaxed though. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Looks pretty good, is there anything special for 135, our is it the same as 91?