# What if a commercial airline pilot misses their flight?

Tags: airliner, pilots

Pilots need to arrive at the airport 1 hour before their departure. What if one of them is not able to report on time (due to any circumstances or reason) and also misses the departure time of flight.

1. In that situation, will the flight get delayed?
2. Will the airline wait for the pilot to come or will they find some other pilot for this flight?
3. Are there any extra pilots always available for handling this kind of situation?
4. What action will be taken against the pilot for missing the flight?
5. Can this type of issue have any effect on a pilot's career (like any kind of ban or suspension or penalty)?

Comment: I would split this question into two: one about the operation, the other about the career.

Comment: Technically I think it is impossible for a pilot to miss his flight ...

Comment: @J.Hougaard -- clever, although one can certainly be ***late*** for one's flight, causing it to be similarly tardy.  And missing "the flight that *was* yours, right up until it wasn't yours any longer because you weren't going to be there for it" is more cumbersome than talking about missing "your" flight.

Comment: On hold for too broad, yet easily answered below...

Comment: Spot on @Michael Hall

Comment: @MichaelHall indeed. A comprehensive answer, dealing with all the connected issues, consequences and solutions to pilots missing their schedule. The subject belongs in one place, rather than in a series of partial questions.

Comment: I agree.  I just wish we didn't have certain individuals shutting the door on competing answers over personal opinion about the question. Yes, there are some bad questions, and it is appropriate to close some, but often keeping a multi-part Q and A in the same location will provide a deeper understanding than if you were to break this into 5 separate parts. What do you say bogl, xxavier, Bianfable, J. Hougaard, and kevin? Why not allow others to answer and let the voters decide?!

Comment: @MichaelHall, I see 6 questions and proposed to split in 2, because I really see two different topics. The point is not if the questions can be answered, but how to deal with different answers that cover only some of the questions.

Comment: Also see the FAQ and related QA on meta: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120633/what-do-we-do-with-multiple-question-questions

Comment: @bogl - You certainly have a right to your opinion, I just don't think you should shut down others on that basis.

Comment: @MichaelHall  Sorry, I didn't shut anybody down. I am not a moderator, and I don't have such privileges. I gave my vote in a regular review process, and in addition I made a constructive suggestion. If you have concerns, questions or doubts about this process, you should really start a discussion on https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/

Comment: "Put on hold as too broad by bogl…"  Scroll up and see for yourself.

Comment: @MichaelHall You might want to have a look at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues-and-how-do-they-work

Comment: OK, I admittedly scanned through it quickly, but I do not see anything in the link refuting my observation that you put this question on hold, thereby squelching any subsequent answers.  Got a quote or section you can refer me to?

Comment: @MichaelHall I am tired of this. The documentation is in front of you. If it is unclear, by all means, please ask a question on Meta!

Comment: Me to.  I provided a specific quote to back my position and you provided nothing to refute it.

Comment: @MichaelHall please come to [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12036/the-hangar). And please be aware that unless a ♦ mod is involved, 5 users are needed to put a question on hold. And that a question on hold is not "shut down", is on hold to be improved before people invest time to answer it.

Comment: An antidotal answer as don’t have an official source but until Flybe recently went out of business, their method was to have a backup crew on call for each airport. If you were on call you had to be able to get to the airport within 60 minutes to cover someone phoning in sick. I believe other airlines run similar setups.

Comment: Sometimes [one of the passengers flies the plane](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=8ywU033RKDc) if a pilot is missing (happened a few days ago in Manchester).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Airlines try to maintain some ratio of crews to fleet to provide surplus bodies to cope with this sort of thing.  For Regionals, where the average aircraft hours are around 2500 hrs per year, and each pilot flies somewhere around 800-1000 hrs per year, you need 3 crews per a/c just to meet the baseline operational need.  Add absentee time for vacation requirements and booking off sick, training etc, and you need 4-5 crews per a/c to be able to sure that you can keep each airplane running 2500 hrs/year.

As a result, Regional operators will try to keep about 8-10 pilots on staff per aircraft and if they are below that, problems start to happen.  You can get by somewhat with crews working overtime, but there are limits to that due to regulatory duty limits.  Airlines have a reserve system to organize crews to make sure there are available idle bodies to step in if required.

There is "reserve" and "ready reserve" duty.  Reserve duty is being on-call at or near home and able to report within a reasonable time of being called, like 2 hours.  These are to cover book-offs with advance notice, like a pilot calling in sick 6 hours before.  Ready reserve duty is where the pilot has to go to the airport crew ops office in uniform and basically hang around ready to go on short notice for someone who doesn't show or who calls in at the last minute.

So:

1. Yes probably, if there isn't a ready reserve pilot on hand.
2. They'll stick in a guy/gal on ready reserve if they have one.  If not, the flight will get delayed or cancelled.
3. See above.
4. Booking off sick or calling in because you had a traffic accident or home crisis isn't a problem.  The problem is failing to call in and leaving people hanging.  You better have a very good reason for not showing up **and** not calling in.  That would result in some kind of disciplinary ding on your record, getting worse if you do it more than once.  It would depend on an airline's union contract, or if non-union, the management's disciplinary policy.
5. In a union shop, for a one time thing, probably not if not repeated.  Union shops give you the luxury of having to screw something up several times to really get hammered for things that are not safety related. It'll depend on contract language; but you could get suspended or let go eventually.  In a non-union shop, it could hurt you in terms of promotion, or if you did it more than once you might get let go more readily than at a unionized airline.

Bottom line is, the next worst thing to unsafe pilots are unreliable pilots.

In the Regional airline business especially, the shortage of crews is really starting to bite and airlines are not able to maintain the necessary staffing "fat" as the flow from the bottom thins out and the majors suck up the experienced crews.  Many cancelled flights with Regional operators are due to lack of crews, not mechanical or weather issues.  The 1500 hr ["Colgan Rule"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colgan_Air_Flight_3407) requirement in the US has made this that much more severe, but up here in Canada where Regionals can still take 250 hour flight school graduates under special programs where they are groomed in-house, there are still not enough to cope with retirements and flights are being cancelled for lack of crews.

This is all tied to the final stages of the movement of the "baby boom" demographic wave, which is now resulting in a flood of retirements of airline capts born in the mid 50s hitting retirement age, which should finally start to taper off in the next 10 years once the peak of the wave is mowing the lawn at home.  Everybody's vacuuming up pilots from the levels below them, resulting in shortages all the way down the chain.

Comment: Worth noting that some of the above also applies to Flight Attendants because dependent on the aircraft a certain number of them is required as well, see [here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/1872/under-what-conditions-is-a-flight-attendant-required-on-an-aircraft) for the regulations.

Comment: Yes good point.  FA's are basically riot cops, trained in the control of crowds and chaos, almost all of whom spend their entire careers working undercover so to speak as stewards and servers.